# Scipy sparse dia_matrix solver

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

In a scipy program I'm creating a dia_matrix (sparse matrix type) with 5 diagonals. The centre diagonal the +1 & -1 diagonals and the +4 & -4 diagonals (usually >> 4, but the principle is the same), i.e. I have a typical PDE system matrix of the form:

```
[ a0  b0  0   0   0   d0  0   0   0  ... 0.0 ]
[ c1  a1  b1  0   0   0   d1  0   0  ... 0.0 ]
[ 0   c2  a2  b2  0   0   0   d2  0  ... 0.0 ]
[ 0   0   c3  a3  b3  0   0   0   d3 ... 0.0 ]
[ 0   0   0   c4  a4  b4  0   0   0  ... 0.0 ]
[ e5  0   0   0   c5  a5  b5  0   0  ... 0.0 ]
[ :   :   :   :   :   :   :   :   :   :  :   ]
[ 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  ... aN  ]
```

When I use scipy.linalg.dsolve.spsolve() to solve the matrix equation it works but I get the following reported back to me

```
>>> SparseEfficiencyWarning: spsolve requires CSC or CSR matrix format
    warn('spsolve requires CSC or CSR matrix format', SparseEfficiencyWarning)
```

If spsolve() is not efficient for solving the sparse matrix type dia_matrix's then what should I be using?

Answer (score 2):

The warning says it all, I think.  Looks like it wants you to use a [`csr_matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix) or a [`csc_matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csc_matrix).

I'm assuming you're creating your matrix with [`scipy.sparse.diags`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.diags.html#scipy.sparse.diags).  You should just be able to use `format = 'csr'` or `format = 'csc'` when you construct the matrix.

Comment: Sorry I've been away at a conference since I posted this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I agree that converting it to a csr/csc matrix will remove the warning, but this is not really my question. I have created a dia_matrix as this is the matrix that best describes my problem. It seems wasteful to convert this to a more general sparse matrix and use the more general sparse matrix solver. As dia_matrix is a standard scipy matrix type I would have assumed there is a linear solver specifically for such matrix's?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit late with this answer, but I hope you found that adding:

```
from scipy.linalg import solve_banded
```

Allows you to use a DIA matrix rather than having to resort to CSR or CSC.

Comment: I did not find this!, I simply resorted to forcing conversion to CSC. Thank you for your late, and more importantly helpful, reply :)

Comment: solve_banded and DIAgonal formats are different; see https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/2285: "Creating dia_matrix objects and then deconstructing them manually to pass to solve_banded is unintuitive and error prone."

Comment: how does this work with off-band diagonals?  like the `d1, d2, ...` in the question?