# Scipy: Solve System with

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am trying to solve the following system of equations:

[image]

I generate a sparse matrix using `scipy.sparse.diags`, and then I want to solve a system of equations. For now, I am using `scipy.sparse.linalg` (apologies for the non-reproducible example):

```
AMatrix = sparse.diags([xx,yy,zz,Param.Lambda[0], Param.Lambda[1]], [-1,0,1,+I, -I])
BMatrix = sparse.diags([BDiag], [0]) - AMatrix
VNew = slinalg.spsolve(BMatrix, bVector)
```

However, sometimes I get

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py:690: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csc_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  SparseEfficiencyWarning)
```

I [found out that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978518/scipy-sparse-dia-matrix-solver) one way would be to enforce (at a loss of performance) a `csr` matrix at creation. Would there be any more performant alternative?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is very broad question. It depends entirely on the nature of your problem to know what type of sparse matrix you'll need. I don't think you'll get many replies. Suggestion: try to reword your question to include more information about the algorithm you're trying to implement.

Comment: @OliverW. do you think adding the image suffices?